# Regex expression for matching only floating point numbers

Tags: c#, regex

Hi i need a Regex Expression for extracting only floating point numbers from right to left

Example string

> Earning per Equity Share (in `) face value of` 2 each26  1,675.10 
>   1,252.56

My current `Regex`

`(\+|-)?[0-9][0-9]*(\,[0-9]*)?(\.[0-9]*)?`  with Rex options-Right to left
but

Current Output is

```
1,252.56 
1,675.10 
26
2
```

However i do not want to match on `26` or `2`

Please help me

Comment: Is it necessary for you to user regex? I think tiny c# program would be the easiest solution

Comment: What is your rule for selection number ? Don't get the last 2 numbers ? or Don't get the number if it is next to a string?

Comment: (+|-)?[0-9][0-9](\,[0-9])?(\.)[0-9]*

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this will help

**Regex**

`/[-+]?[0-9,\.]*([,\.])[0-9]*/g`

**Example input**

> Earning -34 5 b4 pe8r blah4 t3st + - (in) 1,252.56 face
>   -12234,23423.342 of 1,675.10 1,252.56

**Matches**

```
1,252.56
-12234,23423.342
1,675.10
1,252.56
```

---

**Explanation**

`[-+]?` *match a single character present in the list below*

- Quantifier: `?` Between **zero** and **one** time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed *[greedy]*
- `-+` a single character in the list `-+` literally

`[0-9,\.]*` *match a single character present in the list below*

- Quantifier: `*` Between **zero** and **unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed *[greedy]*
- `0-9` a single character in the range between `0` and `9`
- `,` the literal character `,`
- `\.` matches the character `.` literally

*1st Capturing group* `([,\.])`

- `[,\.]` *match a single character present in the list below*

  - `,` the literal character `,`
  - `\.` matches the character `.` literally

`[0-9]*` *match a single character present in the list below*

- Quantifier: `*` Between **zero** and **unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed *[greedy]*
- `0-9` a single character in the range between `0` and `9`

`g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

Comment: `12234,23423.342` isn't something I consider a valid floating point value.

Comment: Fair comment, though it does go a long way to address the original post, and does show some of the down falls

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a `Regex` question this is also taged as `C#`.

Below is an example of how you might get a little bit more control over your output.

It's also culture-specific and only picks up numbers with a decimal place, and has no false positives.

**Method**

```
private List<double> GetNumbers(string input)
{
   // declare result
   var resultList = new List<double>();

   // if input is empty return empty results
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
   {
      return resultList;
   }

   // Split input in to words, exclude empty entries
   var words = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
         
   // set your desirted culture
   var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");

   // Refine words into a list that represents potential numbers
   // must have decimal place, must not start or end with decimal place
   var refinedList = words.Where(x => x.Contains(".") && !x.StartsWith(".") && !x.EndsWith("."));
   foreach (var word in refinedList)
   {
      double value;
      // parse words using designated culture, and the Number option of double.TryParse
      if (double.TryParse(word, NumberStyles.Number, culture, out value))
      {
         resultList.Add(value);
      }
   }
   return resultList;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var testString = "Earning -34 5 b4 , . 234. 234, ,345 45.345 $234234 234.3453.345 $23423.2342 +234 -23423 pe8r blah4 t3st + - (in) 1,252.56 face -12234,23423.342 of 1,675.10 1,252.56";
var results = GetNumbers(testString);
foreach (var item in results)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("{0}", item);
}
```

**Output**

```
45.345
1252.56
-1223423423.342
1675.1
1252.56
```

**Additional Notes**

You can learn more about double.TryParse and its options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can learn more about the CultureInfo Class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.CultureInfo(v=vs.110).aspx).